# How to extract the integer from the string '$61.52' to use in the arithmetic oprations in python?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am using Python.
How to do the addition of the strings `$61.52` and `$57.74` get the value as `119.26`?

I tried using `isdigit()` but it is extracting numbers as `6152` and not as `61.52`. I want to extract `61.52` from string `$61.52`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

```
amount1 = float('$61.52'.replace('$', ''))
amount2 = float('$57.74'.replace('$', ''))

result = amount1 + amount2

print(f'The sum is: ${result:.2f}')
```

Comment: I like this approach. Additionally, one can also put all the special characters inside a list and replace them. `special_char_list = ['-','_','$','&','*']
val = '$34.78*'
for special_char in special_char_list:
    val = val.replace(special_char,'')
print(val)`